# I can't find the header file to include kstat_create method

Tags: c, linux, include, kernel

I'm very new to Linux kernel programming and I'm trying to add a new syscall to my Linux Ubuntu 18.04 system in which I'm using kstat_create and kstat_install methods but I don't seem to find the corresponding header files anywhere. Include lines for these methods on Oracle website are sys/types.h and sys.kstat.h, I have found the linux/types.h instead of sys/types.h but there is no kstat.h anywhere in which the methods above are defined.
I'd appreciate it if you guys could help me. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Those functions are from the Solaris kernel.  You're looking at the wrong OS.

Answer (score 1):

use apt-file to search for the files that you are missing.

These are my search results from ubuntu 16.04. They might be slightly different for 18.04, but this is how you can find them.

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update

$ apt-file search kstat.h
db5.3-doc: /usr/share/doc/db5.3-doc/api_reference/C/lockstat.html
db5.3-doc: /usr/share/doc/db5.3-doc/api_reference/CXX/lockstat.html
db5.3-doc: /usr/share/doc/db5.3-doc/upgrading/upgrade_4_4_lockstat.html
libace-dev: /usr/include/ace/os_include/os_kstat.h
libzfslinux-dev: /usr/include/libspl/sys/kstat.h
python-scipy-doc: /usr/share/doc/python-scipy-doc/h
```

Answer (score 0):

Include this `#include <sys/kstat.h>` in your code for the kstat_create header.